# How do I create a file upload anchor tag link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-file-upload

Below code is working almost correctly but it always displays the "choose file" button. I need the choose file button to not display and all that's left is a link that is a file uploader.

How do I create a file upload anchor tag link properly?

This is using bootstrap-filestyle.

```
$(function(){
  $("#upload_link").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
  });
});

#upload_link{text-decoration:none;}
#upload{display:none}

<input id="upload" type="file"/>
<a href="" id="upload_link">Upload your photo</a>
```

Comment: if I understand this correctly: You do not want to show the user the "Choose File" dialog?  Are you going to be uploading using a standard file name, or you want to roll out your own Choose File dialog?

Comment: correct i don't want to the user the "Choose File" dialog. I just want my own Choose File diag that opens up from an <a> tag. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I finally found a solution! just did some jQuery destroy.(); and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use This CSS

```
    .btn-file {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 120px;
}


.btn-file > input {
    cursor: pointer;
    direction: ltr;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-300px, 0px) scale(4);
}

input[type="file"] {
    display: block;
}
```

Use This HTML

```
<span class="btn default btn-file">
                                <span class="fileinput-new">
                                    Select Document
                                </span>
                                <input type="file" class="textbox wp95 fl fileupload fileInput" name="files" id="fileupload">
                            </span>
```

Comment: that doesn't work. sorry. when i hit "Select Document" i dont get the file upload box. :(

Comment: you also hit anchor tag

Comment: Try this  #upload{display:none; opacity:0;}